# Why does srand need a storage class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is a continuation of my previous question. I've gotten a lot of work done on my black jack project, but now I'm having another issue. I've been stuck on this for three days. At first the issue was that it was giving the same number every time. But then I discovered that the issue was that I needed to use seeding. But for some reason, it says that srand needs a storage class? and when I try to give it one, it just gives me another error. Can somebody help me with this? Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> handone(0);
vector<int> handtwo(0);
int handone_int = 0;
int handtwo_int = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
int starting_hand = rand() % 21 + 1;
int starting_hand_two = rand() % 21 + 1;
string n = "Yes";
int main() {
    std::cout << "Welcome To BlackJack! ";
    std::cout << "Your starting hand is " << starting_hand << "\n";
    while (handone_int < 21 && handtwo_int < 21) {
        for (int i = 0; i < handone.size(); i++) {
            handone_int = handone_int + handone[i];
        } for (int i = 0; i < handtwo.size(); i++) {
            handtwo_int = handtwo_int + handtwo[i];
        }
        cout << "Would you like to keep or hold? ";
        cin >> n; 
        if (n == "keep" or n == "Keep") {

            
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You must call `srand(time(NULL));` inside `main`.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` must be called inside a function, like the first line of `main`. You should also consider moving your global variables inside main and initializing the ones that use `rand()` after the `srand` call.

Comment: The **function** `srand()` does not have a *storage class*, since it is a function.  Functions may be stored in different areas than variables.  Functions cannot be called outside of a function.

Comment: You're getting a `storage class` error message because a function call occurred outside of a function.  The compiler is saying that items declared outside of a function need a *storage class*.  So, move the `srand()` function call inside a function.

Comment: Minor point: It could have been informative to tell us what the 'other error' was. The first error, about the storage class, was misleading. I think the second one might have been more on target. Or not. Compilers can't always help you when what you've written strays outside the norms.

Answer (score 5):

You should put a call of `srand` inside some function body.

Also the variables should be small enough not to cause stack overflow and there are no user-defined functions other than `main()` in this program, so I don't see any reason to use so many global variables. They should be turned to local variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> handone(0);
    vector<int> handtwo(0);
    int handone_int = 0;
    int handtwo_int = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int starting_hand = rand() % 21 + 1;
    int starting_hand_two = rand() % 21 + 1;
    string n = "Yes";

    std::cout << "Welcome To BlackJack! ";
    std::cout << "Your starting hand is " << starting_hand << "\n";
    while (handone_int < 21 && handtwo_int < 21) {
        for (int i = 0; i < handone.size(); i++) {
            handone_int = handone_int + handone[i];
        } for (int i = 0; i < handtwo.size(); i++) {
            handtwo_int = handtwo_int + handtwo[i];
        }
        cout << "Would you like to keep or hold? ";
        cin >> n; 
        if (n == "keep" or n == "Keep") {

            
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: How is that useful though? That call to `srand` appears after all calls to `rand()`. It's practically useless.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well luckily, his question wasn't how to make it useful.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Thank you for pointing out. Updated.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, the correct solution is to not use global variables. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

An *expression statement* is only allowed to appear inside a function. Outside a function, you can only have declarations, *i.e.*, you can only evaluate code in the context of declaring a variable.

The expression statement `srand(time(NULL));` should be moved inside `main`. If for some reason you need it to be done prior to `main`, then you have to put it inside an initializer:

```
int randomizer = (srand(time(NULL)), 0);
```

Comment: It's a definition, not just a declaration.